# command line method to paste file into Thunderbird compose window?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thunderbird, clipboard

I'm trying to paste a 3K file into Thunderbird's "Write" window (i.e. for composing new messages).

This (sometimes) works:

```
date | xclip
# then use middle button to paste
```

This doesn't work:

```
cat /tmp/out.txt | xclip
xclip -o | wc    # just to make sure it got there - reports:      70     309    3233
# press middle mouse in Thunderbird's "Write" window - nothing is pasted
```

But this works:

```
cat /tmp/out.txt | xclip
# open gedit, paste into gedit, then select-all and copy
# paste into Thunderbird
```

Is there a limit to what Thunderbird can accept via the X-clipboard?

Is there another way to insert the contents of a file into a Thuderbird compose window?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is on Thunderbird's end? Is there not a limit to the X clipboard? (Also, any reason for not just attaching this beast?)

Comment: there's something else going on -- even the first example (`date | xclip`) doesn't always work.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the compose command line?

```
thunderbird -compose "to='recipient@domain.com',subject='Test',body='`cat /tmp/out/txt`' "
```

Comment: that's interesting...

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on the web I found that xsel does the trick - I just tested it and will be using it from now on.